# Neo4J Client connection error

Tags: .net, connect, neo4jclient

I'm new to neo4j and having trouble t connect to the Neo4J server wth .NET.

I have installed both the Neo4j DB (v2.2.2) and neo4jclient (v 1.0.0.662) with Install-Package Neo4jclient in Visual Studio, created an empty project with the below code

```
GraphClient Client;
Client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data/"));
Client.Connect();
```

The Problem is that I get an error saying that I'm missing GraphClient.cs. Is there anything else I need to install or download?

Thanks

Comment: Do you definitely have the server running? If you go to http://localhost:7474/ do you see Neo4j?

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: Since this was originally written the client has moved on a bit (any version > `1.1.0.0`), and you can pass in the auth details on construction (which is the *preferred* way):

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("URI"), "User", "Pass"));
```

---

Because you're on 2.2x of Neo4j, you'll have a user/pass element (unless you've turned it off), so you have 2 options, 1 turn off the authentication, 2 send the authentication through with your calls.

#### Method 1 - Disable Authentication

Personally - for local dev work I tend to turn it off. To do this, go to the place you installed Neo4j, and go to the `conf` folder. In there, edit the `neo4j-server.properties` file. Roughly around line 24 there should be a line reading:

```
dbms.security.auth_enabled=true
```

All you need to do is set that to `false` and you should find your connection will work.

#### Method 2 - Send Authentication Details

You'd need to do this for a live version (unless you plan to not use auth with your db), you have two options both detailed here: [Upgrading your Neo4j to 2.2 and having Auth trouble?](http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2015/03/27/upgrading-your-neo4j-from-xxx-to-2.2.0ndashhaving-authorization-trouble.aspx) The quick way is to pass the auth stuff with the URI, so instead of `http://localhost.:7474/db/data` you do something like: `http://username:password@localhost.:7474/db/data`.

The other route involves injecting the *Authentication Header* into all the requests made - you create a client authentication wrapper:

```
private class HttpClientAuthWrapper : IHttpClient
{
    private readonly AuthenticationHeaderValue _authenticationHeader;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public HttpClientAuthWrapper(string username, string password)
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(password))
            return;

        var encoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", username, password));
        _authenticationHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(encoded));
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        if(_authenticationHeader != null)
            request.Headers.Authorization = _authenticationHeader;
        return _client.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

and then inject it into `Neo4jClient` like so:

```
var client = new GraphClient(
    new Uri("http://localhost.:7474/db/data"), 
    new HttpClientAuthWrapper("user", "pass#")
    );
client.Connect();
```

the choice, as they say, is yours.